# Existe diferença entre atribuir valor usando '<-' ou '=' em R?

Tags: r, operadores

Em termos práticos parece não haver diferença, mas debaixo do pano, como a linguagem processa? Há alguma diferença?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Complementando a resposta do Marcus. Um ponto interessante é a [precedencia](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/Syntax.html) desses operadores. O `<-` vem antes de `=`. O que faz com que:

```
> a <- b = 1
Error in a <- b = 1 : não foi possível encontrar a função "<-<-"
```

Não funcione, mas:

```
> a = b <- 1
> a
[1] 1
> b
[1] 1
```

Funcione.

Esse é a único caso que eu já vi dá erro... Mas como é muito incomum, acaba que tanto faz qual for usado.

Inclusive, acabei de ver que este exemplo está no [link da pecedência](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/Syntax.html).

> ```
> ## '=' has lower precedence than '<-' ... so you should not mix them
> ##     (and '<-' is considered better style anyway):
> ## Consequently, this gives a ("non-catchable") error
>  x <- y = 5  #->  Error in (x <- y) = 5 : ....
> ```

Se você ligar para estilo de código, a maioria dos livros recomendam o uso de `<-`. Exemplo:

[Advance R](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Style.html)

> Assignment Use <-, not =, for assignment.
>
> ```
> # Good
> x <- 5
> # Bad
> x = 5
> ```

[Google R Style Guide](https://google.github.io/styleguide/Rguide.xml#assignment)

> Assignment
>
> Use <-, not =, for assignment.
>
> GOOD:
>
> ```
> x <- 5
> ```
>
> BAD:
>
> ```
> x = 5
> ```

---

## Bônus

No RStudio, você pode usar <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>-</kbd> para fazer o `<-`.

Answer (score 10):

Não há diferença na grande maioria dos casos. Os comandos

```
x <- 5
```

e

```
x = 5
```

são idênticos.

Entretanto, se tu quiser atribuir argumentos para uma função, tu é obrigado a usar `=`. Por exemplo, para gerar uma amostra de 10 observações de uma variável aleatória normal com média 5 e desvio padrão 2, apenas o comando

```
rnorm(10, mean = 5, sd = 2)
```

funciona. Não adianta tentar rodar

```
rnorm(10, mean <- 5, sd <- 2)
```

que tu não vai obter o resultado desejado.

---

Particularmente, eu prefiro utilizar `<-` sempre que vou atribuir algum valor a um objeto. Acho mais elegante, pois diferencia da atribuição de argumentos a funções. Mas é só questão de estilo mesmo.

Comment: Rodar `rnorm(10, mean <- 5, sd <- 2)` funciona. Será que isso não varia entre versões do R?